# accessing dedicate server.document-root in lighttpd returns 404

Tags: lighttpd

I have a default lighttpd installation with `server.document-root` = `/var/www/html`

**`/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`**

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_indexfile",
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_redirect",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80

# strict parsing and normalization of URL for consistency and security
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_http-parseoptsDetails
# (might need to explicitly set "url-path-2f-decode" = "disable"
#  if a specific application is encoding URLs inside url-path)
server.http-parseopts = (
  "header-strict"           => "enable",# default
  "host-strict"             => "enable",# default
  "host-normalize"          => "enable",# default
  "url-normalize-unreserved"=> "enable",# recommended highly
  "url-normalize-required"  => "enable",# recommended
  "url-ctrls-reject"        => "enable",# recommended
  "url-path-2f-decode"      => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-2f-reject"      => "enable",
  "url-path-dotseg-remove"  => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-dotseg-reject"  => "enable",
 #"url-query-20-plus"       => "enable",# consistency in query string
)

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.conf.pl"
include "/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/*.conf"

#server.compat-module-load   = "disable"
server.modules += (
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_dirlisting",
    "mod_staticfile",
)
```

Then I have some other webpages under `/var/www/rss` which should be served when I use `https://myip/rss` or when I use `https://rss.mydomain.dev`. So I introduced this config

**`/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/20-tt-rss.conf`**

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/rss/" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/rss"
    dir-listing.activate = "disable"
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/rss/(locale|classes|schema|lock|utils|cache|templates|\.git)/" {
        url.access-deny = ( "" )
    }
    expire.url = (
        "/rss/css/" => "access plus 1 days",
        "/rss/images/" => "access plus 1 days",
        "/rss/js/" => "access plus 1 days",
        "/rss/feed-icons/" => "access plus 1 hours"
    )
} else $HTTP["host"] == "rss.mydomain.dev" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/rss"
    dir-listing.activate = "disable"
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "rss.mydomain.com/(locale|classes|schema|lock|utils|cache|templates|\.git)/" {
        url.access-deny = ( "" )
    }
    expire.url = (
        "rss.mydomain.dev/css/" => "access plus 1 days",
        "rss.mydomain.dev/images/" => "access plus 1 days",
        "rss.mydomain.dev/js/" => "access plus 1 days",
        "rss.mydomain.dev/feed-icons/" => "access plus 1 hours"
    )   
}
```

When using `http://myip/rss/` I get a 404

[image: 404 error]

When using `http://rss.mydomain.dev` I get the "Placeholder page"

[image: Placeholder page]

I am clearly missing something but as new user to lighttpd I don't see what.

Comment: Do the logs say anything useful? Maybe with debug logging enabled?

Comment: nothing in `error.log` and only this in `access.log`: `[02/Feb/2021:08:34:41 +0100] "GET /rss/ HTTP/1.1" 404 341 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"`

Comment: are files from `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/` loaded automatically or does it need to be configured somewhere?

Comment: your config says `include "/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/*.conf"`. I would enable debug logging to get more insights

Answer (score 0):

[lighttpd debug variables](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/DebugVariables) provide noisy details on how lighttpd processes the request, and might be useful to you.

Another option is to `strace -s 1024` the lighttpd process, make a request, and review the filesystem accesses.

lighttpd configuration processing occurs procedurally, in the order configured.  If you have multiple conditions which set `server.document-root`, then the last condition that matches the request and sets `server.document-root` is the one that takes effect for `server.document.root`.  (global settings are treated as if they were set first, no matter where in the config they appear)

While you included your `lighttpd.conf` in the question, you did not include the complete configuration.  Try running `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p` to print the complete configuration.

Aside: incorrect use:
`$HTTP["url"] =~ "rss.mydomain.com/(locale|classes|schema|lock|utils|cache|templates|\.git)/"`
The `$HTTP["url"]` is the url-decoded and normalized url-path.  The url-path does not include the authority ("rss.mydomain.com")
Similarly, your use of `expire.url` with "rss.mydomain.dev" is incorrect.